# not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, syntax

I'm learning Python.  While doing an exercise, I get the error

> Python TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I've searched for an answer, but I don't understand the code I find.

```
print "What's your name?",
name = raw_input()
print "What's your middle name?",
middle_name = raw_input()
print "Where do you live?",
country = raw_input()
print "Make of the car you drive?",
car = raw_input()
print "Are you single or married?",
socstatus = raw_input()
print "Are you Men or Woman?",
sex = raw_input()

print "Let me see if I understood correctly. Your complete name is %r %r, you live in %r, rides on a %r, and you are a %r $r." % (name, middle_name, country, car, socstatus, sex)
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what error you're getting

Comment: your last print statement ends with a `$r` instead of a `%r`

Comment: I recognize that code; you left out the word "cool". :)

Comment: Yeah! that was all thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple syntax problem: your last format specification appears to be **$r** instead of %r.  Because of this, you have only five format specs, but six variables.  Change the last one.

```
print "Let me see if I understood correctly. Your complete name is %r %r,
you live in %r, rides on a %r, and you are a %r %r." % (name, middle_name,
country, car, socstatus, sex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You used $r instead of %r for final variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `$r` in the format string as opposed to a `%r`. However, keep in mind that the %r format-style is deprecated. You should be using str.format() which currently supports positional arguments.

```
# Get variables...
print("Let me see if I understood correctly. Your complete name is {} {}, you live in {}, rides on a {}, and you are a {} {}.".format(name, middle_name, country, car, socstatus, sex))
```